# Is there Muticast routing support on a Cisco 3750?

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, multicast

We have a switch (Cisco WS-C3750G-48TS) with only a C3750-IPBASE-M image (not a 'C3750-IPSERVICES-M' license).  Is there *any* kind of multicast support here?

All I need it to do is route multicast packets to an RP (ip pim sparse-mode).  Do we really need the *service* (C3750-IPSERVICES-M) license/image?.  The uplink switch is running C3750-IPSERVICES-M, but this switch doesn't seem to carry any ability to configure multicast on an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Cisco Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp) the 3750 supports PIM version 1 on the following releases:

- 12.1 EMI Image
- 12.2(50)SE or lower EMI Image or IP Services
- 12.2(52)SE or higher IP Base
- 15.0 IP Base

Comment: Oh, there it is (Cisco Feature navigator).  Thanks!

Comment: cisco Feature Navigator has its shortcut : http://cisco.com/go/fn

Answer (score 2):

I wish I were 100% sure but I'm pretty sure you can do regular IGMP snooping based multicast with the base code on 3750's - we do it one larger boxes but these [instructions](http://www.net130.com/class/tech_handbook/001/Cisco%203750%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf) suggest you can do it on those boxes too.

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of `ip multicast-routing`? That will tell you if you have the capability or not. If not, you will probably need to [upgrade your IOS](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/2239).